# Subclassing a UserControlled GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I'm trying to subclass a GridView that is located in a UserControl.  I want to be able to handle the events in a separate page as a result of this.

Basically I have the code as follows:

My UserControl with a GridView:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="StdList.ascx.cs" Inherits="UCS_Web.uP.UserControls.StdList" %>
<div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

<asp:GridView ID="_gridView" runat="server" PageSize="6" 
        GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        OnRowCommand="_gridView_RowCommand" AutoGenerateEditButton="false" 
        OnDataBound="_gridView_DataBound" OnPreRender="_gridView_PreRender">

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="gridViewHdr" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

A page that uses the UserControl would be like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BypassReasonsPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="UCS_Web.uP.Tools.BypassReasonsPage" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/uP/UserControls/StdList.ascx" TagName="List" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc:List ID="uc_list" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

It's code behind:

```
uc_list.GridView.DataSource = this.TCW.Copy.bypassReasons;
uc_list.GridView.DataBind();
```

To make this page work, I include this file which sets which columns are data bound, etc.:

```
public class BypassReasonsByToolTable : UCS_Web.uP.UserControls.StdList.ICustomTable
{      
  public DataControlField[] Columns
  {
     get
     {
         BoundField col1 = new BoundField();
         col1.DataField = "Code";
         col1.HeaderText = "Code";
         col1.SortExpression = "Code";
         col1.ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(50, UnitType.Percentage);

         BoundField col2 = new BoundField();
         col2.DataField = "Text";
         col2.HeaderText = "Text";
         col2.SortExpression = "Text";
         col2.ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(50, UnitType.Percentage);

         TemplateField editReason = new TemplateField();
         editReason.ItemTemplate = new addTemplate();

         return new DataControlField[] { col1, col2, editReason };
     }
  }
```

I want to be able to have the OnRowCommand, OnRowDelete, and all event handlers in a separate file instead of being in the CodeBehind of the UserControl.  How can I go about making this work?

I tried making them as virtual classes and overriding them on the pages I use them on, but that did not work.  Any other methods that could make this work?

EDIT: UserControl CodeBehind

```
namespace UCS_Web.uP.UserControls
{
   public partial class StdList : UserControl
   {
      private ICustomTable m_custom = null;

protected void _gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (_gridView.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
          for (int i = _gridView.Rows.Count + 1; i <= _gridView.PageSize - 1; i++)
          {
              GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(
                      0,
                      0,
                      DataControlRowType.DataRow,
                  //(i % 2 > 0) ? datacontrolrowstate.normal : datacontrolrowstate.alternate);
                      DataControlRowState.Alternate);

              foreach (DataControlField field in _gridView.Columns)
              {
                  TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                  cell.Text = "&nbsp;";
                  row.Cells.Add(cell);
              }
        //row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:alert();");
              row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff");
              _gridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(i, row);
          }
      }

  }

protected void _gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {

      if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
      {
          //DO MY DELETE STUFF FOR THIS SPECIFIC PAGE
      }
  }
}
```

EDIT: My new override function added to the .cs file (tried many variations, but this is the current)

```
namespace UCS_Web.uP.UserControls
{
public class MyStdList : StdList
{
    protected override void _gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e){
        Response.Redirect("HERPA DERP!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if someone feels this answer is hard to digest. please check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19345/Event-handling-in-a-Gridview-User-Control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your user control is `partial class` right?

See C#'s [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) keyword:

> It is possible to split the definition of a class or a struct, an interface or a method over two or 
>   more source files. Each source file contains a section of the type or
>   method definition, and all parts are combined when the application is
>   compiled.

It could look like this

```
// MyOtherFile.cs:

namespace MyWebSite.UserControls
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            _gridView.OnRowCommand += _gridBiew_RowCommand;
            _gridView.OnDataBound += _gridView_DataBound;
        }

        // events here...
    }
}
```

To override your methods in a subclass, the base class `StdList` needs to have `virtual` methods and/or properties.

See C#'s [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) keyword:

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow 
>   for it to be overridden in a derived class. For example, this method
>   can be overridden by any class that inherits it:

```
  namespace UCS_Web.uP.UserControls
  {
      public partial class StdList : UserControl
      {
          private ICustomTable m_custom = null;

      }

      protected virtual void _gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if (_gridView.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              for (int i = _gridView.Rows.Count + 1; i <= _gridView.PageSize - 1; i++)
              {
                  GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(
                          0,
                          0,
                          DataControlRowType.DataRow,
                      //(i % 2 > 0) ? datacontrolrowstate.normal : datacontrolrowstate.alternate);
                          DataControlRowState.Alternate);

                  foreach (DataControlField field in _gridView.Columns)
                  {
                      TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                      cell.Text = "&nbsp;";
                      row.Cells.Add(cell);
                  }
            //row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:alert();");
                  row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff");
                  _gridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(i, row);
              }
          }
      }

      protected virtual void _gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
      {
              // I do nothing for now... A subclass could override me and do very nice stuff
      } 
  }
```

And...

```
  namespace UCS_Web.uP.UserControls
  {
      public partial class SpecialStdList : StdList { }

      protected override void _gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
      {
          // I do very nice stuff
      } 
  }
```

Comment: so i've added this partial class to my .cs file that drives my .aspx page.  This code does not work directly, but I tried something like _gridView.RowCommand += _gridView_RowCommand and it says it is ambiguous, but if i use a unique name, it never runs.  Could you maybe give an example of one events working similar to above?

Comment: yes, I misunderstood your question I guess :p.. Updated my answer!

Comment: I was never that great at phrasing questions.  But this looks great!  Exactly how I want it to work.  It isn't working yet, but I will mess around with it for a while and I'll hopefully succeed.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something is still not working.  I have setup my override functions and the partial class that will be used to override, but they still never run!  The old virtual function runs no matter what I can't seem to get it to work :(  Any ideas?

Comment: Edit your answer and show us how you actually use your subclass in the context of a webpage.

Comment: It seems to me like you only created a subclass but are not using it anywhere as a code-behind for a user control, right?

Comment: i set the base class of my aspx page .CS file to MyStdList.ICustomTable instead of using "StdList" which was my UC, which would use the partial class with the override in it.  I thought that would be sufficient? (wanna move this to chat?)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19345/Event-handling-in-a-Gridview-User-Control- please chec