# how to override a gridviews event inside a usercontrol in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is my usercontrol

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Grid.ascx.cs" Inherits="WSMP.UserControls.Grid" %>
<a href="#" id="lbtnAhref" runat="server">New</a>
 <a href="#" id="lbtnADel" runat="server">
    Delete</a>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchBy" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchBy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearchBy" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearchBy_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="grdGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="True"
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdGridView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="50" 
    onrowdatabound="grdGridView_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

2 href, 1 dropdownlist, 1 button
1 grid.

My plan is to use this grid in multiple places or multiple pages. So how can I override the RawDataBound of this grid in my page?
Suppose in Page1 if I want to do certain condition, then I will rite in Page1.aspx.cs
For Page2 , I dont need to do that. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Check this out here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031101/subclassing-a-usercontrolled-gridview

Comment: @MayankPathak its quite confusing :(. and from the comments I think that there are some issues still there .

Comment: see the 2nd post...that's marked as an answer...